# Keyboard Input Lag on new 18.10 Install

Tags: drivers, keyboard, performance, 18.10

I recently purchased a new SSD after my old HDD died, and decided do go 100% Ubuntu on it.  The install went smoothly and I love the system, save for the slight lag between typing on my keyboard and seeing letters appear on screen.

The delay is maybe about half a second on average, but it's enough to make the experience of using my terminal feel sluggish.

I'm on a fresh install, using proprietary NVIDIA drivers, and the default gdm3 display manager.  I've been away from Ubuntu for a bit, and I don't quite remember enough about how keyboard input is read to start debugging it.

Any other logs/info I can provide to help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems after upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10.

In my case the problem seems to be not in keyboard at all, but in latency of displaying pressed keys. So after switched to open source drivers rather than NVIDIA via `software & updates -> Additional Drivers -> 'Using X.Org X server'`.

The keyboard lags gone. But it made problems with unable to change standard 640x480 screen resolution with xrandr, and also disabled my audio. After some debugging - all problems simultaneously vanished after `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` in cmd.